# Lowering soil level on mature Japanese maple

Tags: trees, soil

I am removing a raised bed where a mature Japanese maple is located.  Taking soil level down about 8-10 inches and exposing large roots at base of tree.  Will this cause a problem?

Comment: Nope. Taproot is unbothered, and feeder roots are all set. Could be bonsai-like.

Comment: Feeder roots were all set - in the 10" of soil you just removed. Along with the majority of the feeder roots.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you consider killing the tree a problem, then yes, it will cause a problem. If you want to kill the tree, it's a great way to do that. [It may take a few years to die](https://extension.okstate.edu/fact-sheets/site-disturbance-and-tree-decline.html), so if you forget easily you could think the two events were unrelated.

You *might* be able to take off 1/2" every 6 months for 10 years without killing the tree. 10" at once, might as well saw off the tree while you are at it.